# Graphics not plotting in new version

Tags: plotting

There is something in the old version 8 that does not update graphics into my newer Version 11:

```
$Version
ContourPlot[{{x^2-4 x+3==y},{x^2-4 x+4==y},{x^2-4 x+5==y},{y^2-4 y+5==x}},{x,-2,4},{y,-2,4},GridLines->Automatic,ContourStyle->Thick]
NSolve[{y^2-4 y+5==0},y]
ContourPlot[{{x^3-6 x^2+11 x-6==y},{x^3-6 x^2+11 x-6+0.40==y},{x^3-6 x^2+11 x-6+0.80==y},{y^3-6 y^2+11 y-6+0.80==x}},{x,-2,4},{y,-2,4},GridLines->Automatic,ContourStyle->Thick]
NSolve[{y^3-6 y^2+11 y-6+0.80==0},y]
```

Works for computation, but not for plots. Appreciate a fix.

Comment: "into new version 11" should probably be version 12, right? And what is the old version that you compare against?

Comment: I installed Ver11 from older Ver8

Comment: Both plots work for me on V11.3 and V12. What operating system are you on?

Comment: Works if  parabola ContourPlots are separately made and Shown together, but not for  multiple parabolas as above given.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit Windows 7